# UITableView background colour for bottom 5 rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I do know how to input background colours for my row, but I don't really know how I can filter it by only the bottom 5 rows are "cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red;" whereas the rest stays the same. Appreciate those who can help me this thanks!

P.S: Sorry as my swift is quite rusty.

**UITableView Controller**

```
    import UIKit
    import FirebaseDatabase


    var postData2 = [String]()
    var postData3 = [String]()
     var tableDataArray = [tableData]()



    class ResultsController: UITableViewController {


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            ref = Database.database().reference() //set the firebase reference
            // Retrieve the post and listen for changes
            databaseHandle = ref?.child("Posts3").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                postData2.removeAll()
                postData3.removeAll()
                tableDataArray.removeAll()

                for child in snapshot.children {
                    let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                    let key = snap.key
                    let value = String(describing: snap.value!)
                    let rating = (value as NSString).integerValue


                    postData2.append(key)
                    postData3.append(value)
                    tableDataArray.append(tableData(boothName: key, boothRating: rating))


                }
                postData2.removeAll()
                postData3.removeAll()
                let sortedTableData = tableDataArray.sorted(by: { $0.boothRating > $1.boothRating })
                for data in sortedTableData {
                    postData2.append(data.boothName)

                    let value = String(describing: data.boothRating)
                    postData3.append(value)
                }

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }





        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return postData2.count

        }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.init(name: "Helvetica", size: 23)
            cell.textLabel?.text = postData2[indexPath.row]
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = postData3[indexPath.row] + " ♥"
            cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red;
            cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont.init(name: "Helvetica", size: 23)
//        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red;
            return cell

        }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
        {
            return 80
        }

    }

    class tableData {
        var boothName: String
        var boothRating: Int
        init(boothName: String, boothRating: Int) {
            self.boothName = boothName
            self.boothRating = boothRating
        }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What part of this do you need help with? Do you know how to set a background color of a row? Do you know how to check if the indexPath represents one of the last 5 rows?

Comment: I need help with setting a background colour for the last 5 rows of my indexPath

Comment: You didn't answer any of my questions.

Comment: oh shit, my apologies really because i managed to solve it afterwards and was caught up with other troubleshooting errors, really sorry about that

Answer (score 4):

A simple way is to have an conditional check to see if the `indexPath.row` value is within the last five.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    if(indexPath.row >= postData2.count-5){
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }else{
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white /* Remaining cells */
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: All rows will end up being red after some scrolling.

Comment: @rmaddy Good point, didn't realize that. Let me update my answer in a sec.

Comment: @rmaddy damn thght it'll work just fine, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @Miket25 much appreciated for helping me out miket

Comment: It's trivial to fix. Just add an `else` and the other color.

Comment: @rmaddy Oh wow, that's embarrassing, I though I had to subclass these cells for finer control thinking it's the behavior of having reusableCells 

Comment: @Miket25 It is because of the reusable cells. That's why you need to set the background color in both cases. A cell can one time be near the end and red and later on it can be away from the end and need to be white.

Comment: @rmaddy damn it works hahaha, thanks so much rmaddy!! :)

Comment: @Miket25 thank you miket for trying to help me out as well :)

Comment: @Kinja Please don't forget to indicate that your question has been solved by clicking the checkmark to the left of the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

Some of the other answers will work - but it is nicer to use cells that have a known configuration when they are dequeued by `cellForRowAt`, not deal with a bunch of possible starting conditions each time you dequeue a cell. To do this subclass the UITableViewCell and override `prepareForReuse()`. This function will be called just before a cell is returned by `dequeueReusableCell`. Then cells can be set to a known starting point before you configure them. If cells could be received configured any possible way in `cellForRowAt`, you soon wind up with a very long function with a lot of if/else conditions.

The condition

```
if indexPath.row >= postData2.count - 5 {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
```

can be used as it is, and `prepareForReuse` takes care of the cells not keeping any settings when they are recycled. Here's an example:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}
```

With this one simple setting it's a wash whether you do the if/else approach or use subclassing to make the most of `prepareForReuse`. But as soon as you have more than one thing to set in a cell you will find it is far less complex to use this function and results in far fewer mistakes with the appearance of cells - consider what would happen if there were more than one possible color a cell could be, or there were multiple elements in the cell to be configured with multiple possible values...

Comment: You should mentioned what needs to be put in `prepareForReuse` in this case.

Comment: OK, prepareForReuse added.

Comment: Also, one last thing, do yall know whats a better/efficient way for the code in my image attached? because i feel having 2 if statements is quite redundant/ugly. or do u feel its ok ? https://ibb.co/ecp3XR

Comment: Hard to say for sure without knowing more about what selectedTab is, but you could always put both conditions on one line with &&.

Answer (score 2):

You can add simple logic

```
if indexPath.row >=(postData2.count-5) {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}else {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check a condition for setting the red colour for last five rows.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    if(indexPath.row >= postData2.count-5){
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red;
    }else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white; //white colour for other rows
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method is recommended by the system, this method is more circumventing reuse in some cases (like when you modify the contents of a control in the cell surface)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    // Not the type of cell, if the queue will return nil, at this time requires create ⼀ cell
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
}
```

If it involves data processing, you can create a new NSMutableSet(), Used to store your operations (ordinary data is lost, stored in the didSelecetRow inside indexPath like) save anyway, a unique tag.

These are just solve the problem of multiplexing, to deal with discoloration, refer to the above solution.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    if(indexPath.row >= postData2.count-5){
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }else{
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white /* Remaining cells */
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: This is a very confusing answer. The 2nd block is code is the proper solution. What is the 1st half of the question all about?

Comment: I see you have said, sliding up and down there will be reuse problems, put the cell reuse code to write up

Comment: In fact, I want to copy the above paragraph, the result did not see that there is already a solution